# Definite integration by substitution problem with the substitution $x=e^u−e^{−u}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> I'm stuck at the following integration problem:
>
> a) Given that $x = e^u - e^{-u}$, find an expression for $e^u$ in terms of $x$.
>
> b) Use the substitution $x = e^u - e^{-u}$ to find the exact value of $\int_0^1 \frac {1} {\sqrt {4+x^2}}\, dx$.

My textbook says that the solutions are:

a) $e^u=\frac {x+\sqrt{x^2+4}}{2}$

b) $\ln\frac {1+\sqrt5}{2}$

I have tried some algebraic manipulation in task a) but this did not bring me far. The textbook solutions looks pretty much like the result of the quadratic formula but I do not know if this is a coincidence or not.

I did not understand b) either since I lack the understanding of task a). I might be able to solve it because you could use the substitution $u =\frac x 2 $ because this nicely leads to $\int_0^1 \frac 1 {\sqrt{u^2+1}}\,du $ and then I one could trig-substitution but I cannot solve it with the given substitution.

Could somebody tell me I can solve or even approach the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiplying by $e^u$, you get
$$
x = e^u-e^{-u}\Leftrightarrow x e^u = (e^u)^2-1\Leftrightarrow (e^u)^2-x e^u-1=0
$$

solving the quadratic equation, you conclude that

$$
e^u = \frac{x \pm \sqrt{x^2+4}}{2}
$$

but the minus sign does not yield any solution and you finally arrive at
$$
e^u = \frac{x + \sqrt{x^2+4}}{2}.
$$

Regarding the integral,

\begin{align*}
\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+4}}dx = \int_0^{\log \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}} (e^u+e^{-u})\frac{1}{e^u+e^{-u}} du = \log \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}
\end{align*}

---

Note:
$$
e^u = \frac{x+\sqrt{x^2+4}}{2} \Rightarrow \sqrt{x^2+4} = 2e^u -x = 2e^u-(e^u-e^{-u}) = e^u+e^{-u}
$$

Comment: I did not get the idea of multiplying by $e^u$ although it seems obvious in retrospect. But now it is also clear to me how the task works and how a) relates to b). Thank you very much!

Comment: @DavidA.: I'm glad you have solved this problem. With regard to multiplying by $e^u$, it gets easier to spot things like that with experience, but notice how we end up with a quadratic in $e^u$. If we set $z=e^u$, then we have $x=z-z^{-1}$, and now it seems more obvious to multiply by $z$ to obtain a quadratic in $z$, which gives us $zx = z^2 - 1$ and so $z^2 - xz - 1 = 0$. Then, solve for $z$, and check that the solutions work by substituting $e^u$ back in for $z$.

Answer (score 1):

For b) note $\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2+4}}=\frac{(e^u+e^{-u})du}{\sqrt{e^{2u}+2+e^{-2u}}}=du$, so the integral is $\int_0^{\ln\tfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}}du=\ln\tfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$.